# How to capture html frame as an image

Tags: javascript, python, browser, printscreen

I need to open a webpage from Python and capture what I see in browser as an image(or rather what should be seen, because I want to execute it in background). 
The webpage contains JavaScript - one frame has caption dependent on script evaluation and I want it also to be captured.

Comment: What browser? What OS? this is more to do with scripting the browser in question than manipulating the HTML in any meaningful way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's feasible, at least, using [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/news) + QWebKit (an example [here](http://lateral.netmanagers.com.ar/tr/es/weblog/posts/BB901.html) and [here](http://www.blogs.uni-osnabrueck.de/rotapken/2008/12/03/create-screenshots-of-a-web-page-using-python-and-qtwebkit/)).

Comment: Thanks for this hint! Do You have idea what will libraries will I need to make it work? What browser, OS requirements?

Comment: @Lewy. You need Pyqt, any OS, no browser needed.